# Consumir API de Facebook en PHP

Tags: facebook

Hola me gustaria consumir la **API de facebook** en HP
Me gustaria que este me dejara entrar en una pagina como tal de **Facebook**
Soy nueva y necesito consumirlo ya sea en PHP o en C#, la verdad el codigo lo tome, asi que me sale un error de

> require_once(src/Facebook/autoload.php): failed to open stream en la linea 2, espero que me puedan ayudar, Gracias!

```
<? php require_once 'src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{id}',
  'app_secret' => '{contraseña}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

try {
  // Requires the "read_stream" permission
  $response = $fb->get('/me/feed?fields=id,message&amp;limit=5');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

// Page 1
$feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();

foreach ($feedEdge as $status) {
  var_dump($status->asArray());
}

// Page 2 (next 5 results)
$nextFeed = $fb->next($feedEdge);

foreach ($nextFeed as $status) {
  var_dump($status->asArray());
}
?>
```

Comment: Eso es netamente porque no encuentra el archivo 'autoload.php'

Comment: de hecho esta en la misma carpeta el archivo donde se indica

Comment: y que permisos tiene ese documento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instalaste correctamente composer? si es asi, donde tengas tu codigo, en la carpeta raiz debe existir la carpeta vendor y de ahi puedes consumir el API

Comment: hice los pasos, y pero no me aparece la carpeta vendor

Comment: segun el [SDK] (https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk?fbclid=IwAR1T1RbPVAgabVuc-55qsKs0hnIv1Peyt2beHqx629MqSplb4bhw6moiQ5w) de fb solamente corre el comando ```composer require facebook/graph-sdk```

Comment: ya me quito el error pero no me deja publicar nada :3